# Update DrawString at certain interval

Tags: java, swing, timer, calendar, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make a digital clock which then adds to a `JPanel`, Now when I call `DrawString` outside of the `taskPerformer` method it draws but when inside, it does not draw the String! Why is this and how would I go about implementing this class so that it redraws every second?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;     
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class DrawDate extends JPanel {
public Date ddate;
public Calendar ccalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
Date time;

public DrawDate() {
    this.ddate = new Date();
    time = this.ccalendar.getTime();
}

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50);
g2.setFont(font);
//THIS DRAWS THE STRING
g2.drawString(time.toString() , 100, 100); 

ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Calendar ccalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date time = ccalendar.getTime();
            //THIS DOES NOT DRAW A STRING.
            g2.drawString(time.toString() , 200, 100);

    }
};
final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
timer.start();


}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    super.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
    paint(g);
}

}
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html?printOnly=1 might be worth a read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you have a context problem. `g2` has no context within the `ActionListener`, but there are other issues that need to be solved first...

Don't create the `ActionListener` or `Timer` within a `paint` method, in fact you should avoid overriding `paint` at all.

`paint` is suppose to call `paintComponent`, but because you've neglected to call `super.paint`, this won't happen, therefore your `paintComponent` method will never be called. But, you should avoid calling `paint` from within the `paintComponent` method

Instead, create the `Timer` and `ActionListener` in something like the constructor.  When the `Timer` ticks/triggers the `actionPerformed` method, simply update the value you want painted and then call `repaint`.

In the `paintComponent` method, do the actually rendering.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Oddly, the original code had overridden both methods, and in `paintComponent(..)`  it caused an infinite loop by setting the BG color..  Definitely the OP should go through the  two links you added.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The problem is, they never call super.paint, therefore paintComponent won't event be called...yet...

Comment: Oops!  I *meant* to write *"..it **would have** caused an infinite loop by setting the BG color"*  - That's my story, and I'm sticking to it.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson That's what I first thought ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

> datePanel.add(new ClockPane());

```
  public class ClockPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel clock;

        public ClockPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            clock = new JLabel();
            clock.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            clock.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32f));
            tickTock();
            add(clock);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tickTock();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        public void tickTock() {
            clock.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

See tips in comments in the code..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class DrawDate extends JPanel {

    public Date ddate;
    public Calendar ccalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date time;

    public DrawDate() {
        this.ddate = new Date();
        time = this.ccalendar.getTime();

        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    Calendar ccalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    Date time = ccalendar.getTime();
                    //THIS DOES DRAW A STRING.
                    repaint();
            }
        };
        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();

        // this will invoke repaint()
        // if called within a paint/paintComponent - infinite loop
        super.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        g2.setFont(font);

        // update the time
        time = new Date();
        //THIS DRAWS THE STRING
        g2.drawString(time.toString() , 10, 100);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600,150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new DrawDate());
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```